# How to get head revision number of a file, or the changelist number when it was checked in / changed

Tags: python, python-2.7, perforce

I'm writing a python app that connects to perforce on a daily basis. The app gets the contents of an excel file on perfoce, parses it, and copies some data to a database. The file is rather big, so I would like to keep track of which revision of the file the app last read on the database, this way i can check to see if the revision number is higher and avoid reading the file if it has not changed.

I could make do with getting the revision number, or the changelist number when the file was last checked in / changed. Or if you have any other suggestion on how to accomplish my goal of avoiding doing an unnecessary read of the file.

I'm using python 2.7 and the perforce-python API

Comment: Do you create a new client to connect everyday?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Several options come to mind.

1. The simplest approach would be to always let your program use the same client and let it sync the file. You could let your program call `p4 sync` and see if you get a new version or not. Let it continue if you get a new version. This approach has the advantage that you don't need to remember any states/version from the previous run of your program.
2. If you don't like using a fixed client you could let your program always check the current head revision of the file in question: 
   `p4 fstat //depot/path/yourfile |grep headRev | sed 's/.*headRev \(.*\)/\1/'`
   You could store that version for the next run of your program in some temp file and compare versions each time.
3. If you run your program at fixed times (e.g. via cron) you could check the last modification time (either with `p4 filelog` or with `p4 fstat`) and if the time is between the time of the last run and the current time then you need to process the file. This option is a bit intricate since you need to parse those different time formats.